# Apache htaccess being processed after proxy directives

Tags: apache-2.4, .htaccess, reverse-proxy

I'm running Apache 2.4 on Linux. I have a working `.htaccess` file.

As a test I'm doing the redirecting `/ws/xyz123` to `https://www.google.com`.

So I request `http://example.com/ws/xyz123` and I get redirected correctly to google.

The problem arises when I put in a reverse proxy for the `/ws` directory as follows:

```
ProxyPass        /ws http://192.168.25.2:7003/ws retry=0
ProxyPassReverse /ws http://192.168.25.2:7003/ws
```

The proxying works fine but the `.htaccess` is now ignored.
If I comment out the proxy lines the `.htaccess` is back working again.
I need both working.
Is there a way to allow the `.htaccess` work with the proxy in place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ProxyPass /ws http://192.168.25.2:7003/ws` is just an **alternative syntax**  for the [`ProxyPass`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass), equivalent to

```
<Location "/ws">
    ProxyPass "http://192.168.25.2:7003/ws"
</Location>
```

When you use the mod_proxy inside `<Location>`, Apache never looks into the directory (with the same path relative to `DocumentRoot`), omitting all the directives in your `.htaccess` file.

You should move the directives to your server configuration i.e. use them in `<Location>` or `<VirtualHost>` contexts instead of `.htaccess` context.

Comment: The issue here is as follows, I am modifying the htaccess to prevent access at certain times to /ws/x then maybe /ws/y (all generated automatically)

Comment: You can't. Just move the directives to a context from where they are applied.

Comment: So there is no way to use the htaccess for this scenario

Comment: No way... and no need. I already explained, why.